# Bootstrap v5 Carousel not working 2Shine DNN Theme

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Hopefully this will be seen by the great folks at 2sxc!

We recently started using your 2shine DNN Theme, and loving it, but we bumped into a weird situation that we can't figure out.  If we add try any of the Bootstrap v2 Carousel (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/) examples in a DNN page with the 2shine theme applied, the carousel doesn't work.

Specifically, the images within the carousel do show on the page, but:

- the images run down the page (all shown)
- when we use the frame selector or next/prev buttons they have no styling/content (just small, maybe 10 x 3px standard html buttons
- there are no js errors in the dev console

Can you tell us what we're missing?

I cannot provide a live URL (publicly), but if you provide a twitter, discord, or whatever, I can privately provide the site/page.

Thanks!

For anyone else....

- DNN version is 9.10.2
- Yes, DNN is including BSv5 via the 2Shine skin (https://2shine.org/)
- Yes, DNN is including jQuery

Answer (score 1):

just fyi: you don't need jquery for this.

to me it sounds like you're missing some CSS.

1. Do you see any red CSS requests in the network?
2. Do you see the css being loaded
3. for comparison - do you have a page / site where it works, so you can compare the styles in F12

Just in case you have client-dependency activated, make sure you bump the version in case something failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Debugger Tools Console window.  You’ll probably see a JavaScript error.

Comment: That's the strange part -- no console errors or info about the carousel, in fact no JS errors at all (page/site/code are fairly simple and tje console is "clean").  The only thing I can think of is that the 2Shine theme from 2SXC isn't properly including something from bootstrap, jquery or otherwise -- but strangely, everything else (thus far anyways) seems to be working just fine.  Thanks for the suggestion!